# Get the new value from an input with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to convert a JQuery website to AngularJS, but I can't figure this one out.
**In JQuery I used:**

```
$('.bet').change(function(e)  {
    // Do someting
};
```

I tried to do multiple things with AngularJS but no success.
At the moment I have this in my HTML and I have nothing related in my Angular file

**index.php**

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="bet" name="bet" placeholder="Your bet" ng-model="bet" ng-change="bet( {{bet}} )"/>
```

How to do this in AngularJS?

Comment: what is the desired result that you would like to obtain? when the users types something, what do you want to do with the value?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> Evaluate the given expression when the user changes the input. The expression is evaluated immediately, unlike the JavaScript onchange event which only triggers at the end of a change (usually, when the user leaves the form element or presses the return key).

So basically you need to bind a function to a `ng-change` attribute, like this way:

```
<input type="number" name="bet" placeholder="Your bet" ng-model="bet" ng-change="betChanged(bet)"/>
```

and the listener in your controller:

```
$scope.betChanged = function(bet){
   //do something...
   console.log(bet);
}
```

Like this, betChanged will be called every time bet will change, much like the native javascript `input` function.

Comment: *"much like the native javascript change"* not true .... more like *'input'* event. It even says that in your docs quote

Comment: My bad, i'll edit my answer. thanks for pointing me that out.

Comment: Binding to the `ng-change` attribute is correct, however passing the `bet` into `$scope.betChanged` is unnecessary since you have access to the same variable via `$scope.bet`

Comment: Yeah it's a matter of coding style: you are right it's not necessary, but in my opinion is more clear to understand

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.bet = "";
  $scope.onBetChanged = function () {
    alert($scope.bet);
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="bet" name="bet" placeholder="Your bet" ng-model="bet" ng-change="onBetChanged()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: note that `ng-change` responds differently than jquery change

Answer (score 0):

what about **$watch**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        First Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>

        Full Name: {{firstName }}
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
            $scope.$watch('firstName', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log('oldValue=' + oldValue);
                console.log('newValue=' + newValue);
                //do something
                $window.alert("Event fired");
            });
        });
    </script>
```